# how to get only row two in result query in mysql?

Tags: php

[image]

in image result my query mysql. how to get only row 2 using PHP?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.. Do you mean only select the `baris` column? Or do you mean where the value is equal to `2` ?

Comment: echo $result['baris']; how to get to only row to

Answer (score 0):

If you mean row with `2` use this,

```
select * from table_name where baris = 2;
```

If you want to fetch only second row

```
select * from table_name LIMIT 1, 1;
```

If you want to use `ORDER BY` clause, you can use that as well(This is only if you are looking for `2nd largest or 2nd smallest`.)

Comment: the above table is the result of a mysql query, I ask how where displays only the second row I

Comment: while fetching the result, fetch only one row. then display that one row.

Comment: how to display in array result only row to? $result[2]; ?

Comment: use my second query. you will get only 1 row, that is your second row.

Comment: I have to show my mysql query above, image table this result my query

Comment: add `limit 1,1` at last.

Answer (score 0):

this my query

```
        SELECT SUM(nilai.nilai) as total, COUNT(nilai.nilai) as baris FROM nilai JOIN data_nilai
         ON nilai.id_data_nilai = data_nilai.idx
            WHERE data_nilai.id_tahun_ajar = '1' 
                AND data_nilai.id_sekolah = '1040902040' 
                AND data_nilai.id_kelas = '2' 
                AND data_nilai.id_rombel = '2' 
                AND data_nilai.id_mapel = '13' 
                AND data_nilai.status_nilai = '0' 
                AND data_nilai.id_jn = '1'
                AND nilai.user_id = 'IDS0000707'
    UNION
    SELECT SUM(nilai.nilai) as total, COUNT(nilai.nilai) as baris FROM nilai JOIN data_nilai
         ON nilai.id_data_nilai = data_nilai.idx
            WHERE data_nilai.id_tahun_ajar = '1' 
                AND data_nilai.id_sekolah = '1040902040' 
                AND data_nilai.id_kelas = '2' 
                AND data_nilai.id_rombel = '2' 
                AND data_nilai.id_mapel = '13' 
                AND data_nilai.status_nilai = '0' 
                AND data_nilai.id_jn = '2'
                AND nilai.user_id = 'IDS0000707'

    UNION
        SELECT SUM(nilai.nilai) as total, COUNT(nilai.nilai) as baris FROM nilai JOIN data_nilai
         ON nilai.id_data_nilai = data_nilai.idx
            WHERE data_nilai.id_tahun_ajar = '1' 
                AND data_nilai.id_sekolah = '1040902040' 
                AND data_nilai.id_kelas = '2' 
                AND data_nilai.id_rombel = '2' 
                AND data_nilai.id_mapel = '13' 
                AND data_nilai.status_nilai = '0' 
                AND data_nilai.id_jn = '3'
                AND nilai.user_id = 'IDS0000707'
    UNION
        SELECT SUM(nilai.nilai) as total, COUNT(nilai.nilai) as baris FROM nilai JOIN data_nilai
         ON nilai.id_data_nilai = data_nilai.idx
            WHERE data_nilai.id_tahun_ajar = '1' 
                AND data_nilai.id_sekolah = '1040902040' 
                AND data_nilai.id_kelas = '2' 
                AND data_nilai.id_rombel = '2' 
                AND data_nilai.id_mapel = '13' 
                AND data_nilai.status_nilai = '0' 
                AND data_nilai.id_jn = '8'
                AND nilai.user_id = 'IDS0000707'
```

Comment: @niranjan .. this my query